# how to remove duplicate sequences in a FASTA file?

Tags: python, pandas, biopython, fasta

I have a FASTA file which sort with dates and I want to remove duplicate sequences in which every sequence that is older stays and other sequences which they date after the first one, remove, I found this code for removing duplicates sequences and I think because my sequences are sort it does that job for me but because my file is too big I need a more efficient way

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import time

start = time.time() 

seen = set()
records = []

for record in SeqIO.parse("b4r2.fasta", "fasta"):  
    if record.seq not in seen:
        seen.add(record.seq)
        records.append(record)


#writing to a FASTA file
SeqIO.write(records, "OUTPUT-FILE.fasta", "fasta")
end = time.time()

print(f"Run time is {(end- start)/60}")
```

what do you guys suggest for this task?

Comment: More efficient in terms of memory or CPU? If the latter, you could try parallelizing but you would need a synchronized data structure instead of a simple set

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski More efficient in terms of memory I mean

Comment: That's trickier since a duplicate sequence pair could appear across the whole file. You could save the findings to a database if you don't have enough RAM but that will make it significantly slower.

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski So there is no way, I can't do with the database cause my data is too large so it will take forever to does this job, thank you for your help